# Out of these two ways to chain extension methods, is there any reason to use one over the other?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, method-chaining

Say I have an overloaded extension method with the following two signatures:

```
public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Foo foo);
public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Foo foo, Bar bar);
```

I'd like to chain one method to the other. I can do this in one of two ways:

**Chaining Technique #1**

```
public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Foo foo)
{
    // Call overload using extension method syntax.
    foo.MyExtensionMethod(new Bar());
}

public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

**Chaining Technique #2**

```
public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Foo foo)
{
    // Call overload as a regular method.
    MyExtensionMethod(foo, new Bar());
}

public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

This is my question: Is there any difference between calling the overloaded method as an extension method versus as a regular method? If so, what's the difference? Is one preferable to the other?

Comment: I prefer #1 since it makes clear that the extension method is called IMHO.

Comment: I don't think this is Chaining.  This is overloading.  Chaining would be `foo.Bar1().Bar2();`

Comment: @cadrell0 - As I understand the term, this is method chaining. `foo.Bar1().Bar2();` is object chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is actually more stable.  The first one will be changed if I do something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void MyExtensionMethod(Bar bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("instance method");
    }
}
```

If I add this then in the first case it calls the instance method, and in the second case it calls the extension method.

Comment: I did mean for it to be the same throughout. I've amended my question to fix the typo.

Comment: True... but I think it would be a horrible idea to name an extension method the same as an instance method.

Comment: -1 Completely unrealistic scenario. Though correct, this is a real stretch.

Comment: @AndrewBarber such things often happen unintentionally.  For example, people will often add extension methods to library classes for convenience, and on occasion new versions of the language will come out with another method of the same name.  I have heard of (but not experienced) bugs resulting from this.  Clearly the example method of MyExtensionMethod on class Foo is meant to be extrapolated.

Comment: @Servy Your argument is somewhat specious; Taking it to its logical conclusion, you should *never* use Extension methods at all - just use a static method instead... because a new version of a library could match your extension method's signature. *That's really what you are arguing here, after all*. -1

Comment: @Oded I don't see how it's unrealistic at all.  Additionally why downvote an answer that's right just because it's not something that comes up daily?

Comment: I suggest you read your last comment and consider why you downvoted every other answer on this question.

Comment: @Servy it's something that *might*, extremely rarely, have a tiny chance to perhaps come up every few *years*... and is completely irrelevant for a stable application that isn't *using* new versions of a library.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I would most certainly say that people should be careful of extension methods.  When dealing with classes you control it's not a problem at all, but often the reason people use extension methods in the first place is *because* they don't control the class.  Regardless, I am merely stating the *fact* that the two methods are not identical.  There is a case in which they act differently.  That information is important to know so that you can prevent this case from ever coming up.  If you want to assert that it never has I can go look for counter-examples.

Comment: @Oded I downvoted the answers that made statements that were factually incorrect.  That, to my understanding, is the purpose of the voting system.  I also removed the downvote for the answer that corrected it's factual mistake.

Comment: I also fail to see why people think this is something that is so uncommon.  There are a number of libraries out there of extension methods.  The reason that the (generally) exist is that something was left out of the definition of the library class(es) they extend.  The writers of these libraries (sometimes 3rd party, sometimes language) often take note of this and include the [missing] functionality in future releases.

Comment: +1 because the answer is correct, and I learned something from it.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it best serves my motive for asking this question in the first place. I already knew that in most cases either technique would work, but I was looking for small technical details that might differentiate one from another and make one more preferable.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the compiler is able to resolve everything, they should be emitted as equivalent MSIL. Extension methods are just compiler tricks; they *are* static methods in reality.

Servy notes in his answer that if you have an instance method with the same name, you can run into problems. *I agree*... and as a result, strongly urge you *never* to name an extension method the same as any instance method.

Answer (score 3):

I find your technique 2 to be more natural to read.

The first one is a bit jarring - I need to figure out that it calls a second extension method.

So, on readability alone, I would select technique 2.

In terms of how things get called - extension methods are just syntactic sugar for calls to static methods. Both examples amount to the same thing.

---

There is one exception, as noted in the answer by @Servy - if you have an instance method with the exact same name and parameters (bar the first `this` parameter), you can have issues. Though unlikely to occur in your own code base, this may happen - just a consequence of using extension methods.

It is bad practice to do this - don't name instance methods the same as extension methods.

Comment: See my answer.  There is an exceptional case that distinguishes them.  Usually they are the same thing, but not always.

Answer (score 3):

This question is equivalent to asking "is there a difference between calling an extension method as an extension versus as a static method?". The answer is no. The compiler translates both calls to the same code.